# TCP DUP ACK/Out-of-Order/Previous segment not captured/Retransmission flooded on wireshark logs

Tags: networking, tcp, internet, isp, slow-connection

Due to slow network, I installed wireshark on the device(laptop) to find this

[image: wireshark]

This is a log of the device using internet(Downloading a file),as you can see at the right end of the screenshot, the whole log is full of these TCP  DUP ACK/Out-of-Order/Previous segment not captured/Retransmission /Fast restransmission/Spurious Retransmission.
many times it is full of red "RST" packets and some times even destination port unreachable to dns address(8.8.8.8)

What I have tried:
1)Tested on different networks (two wifi broadband providers and 2 4g hotspots from phone), the result is same, even when connected via Ethernet cable
2)Tried reinstalling network drivers and also factory reset on device
3)Keeping the device idle while connected still show them but far less than when actively using internet or downloading

Why does this happen and what shall I try to fix it?
Could this be in any way a possibility that the device is being targeted by hackers?

Answer (score 2):

> Could this be in any way a possibility that the device is being targeted by hackers?

Almost certainly not.  Retransmissions and out of order packets are the result of congestion or other packet loss between your computer and the remote end.  It could be something on your network, or something on the Internet, or both.

The *Previous segment not captured* messages mean that Wireshark is seeing an acknowledgement for a packet it didn't capture.  This possibly because the computer running Wireshark can't keep up or packet loss.

Some errors like this are to be expected, even in in a normal network.  I can't tell from this small sample if this is a momentary loss, or an indication of a more serious problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, maybe the device cannot keep u due to some faulty hardware. Also I have mentioned this, "as you can see at the right end of the screenshot, the whole log is full of these". That is the scroll bar showing a very long log full of black stripes, the packets are all the same  I mentioned.